# MySQL: modeling for 90 yes or no questions survey with statistics support

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-modeling

I'm trying to design MySQL tables for survey.

The survey is composed of 6 sets of questions, 15 questions for each set, so total 90 questions. **The questions and the order of questions are not gonna be changed, and there are some possibility for new set of questions(also 15 questions per set) to be added.**

They are all 'yes or no' questions so the answers will be saved as true or false in boolean way.

I also save sex, nationality, age of users for statistics.

1. I wanna get the percentage of the same answers between two users.
2. I wanna get the percentage of the same answers between one person and majority(majority is the answer of more than 50%).
3. I wanna get the statistics of yes or no per question by combination of sex, nationality, age. For example, **66% answered yes for question no.11** or **12% of Korean women answered no for question no.86**

So I made a table to support all those features

> questions table

```
 q_id PK(1 to 90)
 q_text VARCHAR(100)
```

> users table

```
u_id PK
sex TINYINT
nationality VARCHAR(20)
age TINYINT UNSIGNED
q_1 TINYINT
q_2 TINYINT
...
q_90 TINYINT
```

Is it okay to have 94 columns in one table? I'm afraid the number of columns will increase as I add some questions sets. So I splited answers to set table

> set1 table

```
s_id PK
u_id users_table
q_1 TINYINT
q_2 TINYINT
...
q_15 TINYINT
```

> set2 table

```
s_id PK
u_id users_key
q_16 TINYINT
q_17 TINYINT
...
q_30 TINYINT
```

and so on. I now have 6 set tables and I now can add new table if I add new set.
I searched a little about this and I saw that it would be better if I have a separate table for answers

> answer table

```
a_id PK
u_id users_key
q_no question number(1~90)
answer TINYINT
```

I'm afraid that answers table may grow too big because answers table get 90 rows per user.
I'm really not sure which design is better. I've searched stackoverflow for answers but I couldn't find appropriate answer for yes or no survey.

Comment: More rows on same structured data = perfectly fine.  More columns as you add questions changing DDL is bad design. Adding data is, MUCH more often than not, preferable to changing structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating all those columns q_x is crazy, you just need to create a table called question_set with all the question like :

```
 s_id PK
 s_type (you can put 1, 2, 3 for set group)
 q_id FK(questions)
```

You should normalize your table, putting all those columns will sooner than later create you problems. In the case you need to denormalize it is better to create views for that.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use [foreign keys](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) to make it more flexible.

So I would create

`set_table
set_id PK
set_name Text`

`question_table
question_id PK`

`//This will help you put same question in multiple sets 
question_set
set FK (set_table)
question FK (question_table)`

`user_table
user_id PK
user_name Text
sex Text`

`user_answer_table
user FK(user_table)
question FK(question_table)
answers Bool`

Then you can write complex queries with joins to get all the metric you need. This will give you plenty of flexibility to add new questions, sets, users without the need to change the schema.

Comment: You need a question_set table so you know what questions are in each set and a question could be re-used in different sets.  putting the set on the question table limits the re-use of questions.